# Using 2 variables in Switch statement

Tags: java, switch-statement

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Test {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    String charr;

    try{    
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter the Value ");

      charr = sc.next();
      switch (charr +"|"+ charr) {
        case "a|A" : System.out.println("a | A"); break;
        case "b|B" : System.out.println("b | B"); break;
        case "c|C" : System.out.println("c | C"); break;
        case "d|D" : System.out.println("d | D"); break;
        default:  System.out.println("You are doing it wrong");
      }
    } catch(java.util.InputMismatchException e) {
      System.out.println("Exception thrown :" + e);
    }

    System.out.println("Out of Block");
  }
}
```

Hello all, my program is to to input only 1 character, but my switch statement can identify the small letter or capital letter.

Comment: **java != javascript**..

Comment: try to lower any input and only compare with the lower chars....

Comment: it will not compile unless u r  using java 7

Comment: I want it to check both the characters. A & a in the same case.

Comment: It will never find a match, since in your switch you add two |'s, while in your cases you only have 1. As A. S. suggested, charr=charr.toLowerCase();
and compare them against "a", "b", ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use multiple cases to identify lower and upper case letters:

```
switch (charr) {
    case "a": case "A" : System.out.println("a | A"); break;
    case "b": case "B" : System.out.println("b | B"); break;
    case "c": case "C" : System.out.println("c | C"); break;
    case "d": case "D" : System.out.println("d | D"); break;
    default:  System.out.println("You are doing it wrong");
}
```

However an easier alternative would be to convert to lower or upper case before checking:

```
switch (charr.toLowerCase()) {
    case "a": System.out.println("a | A"); break;
    case "b": System.out.println("b | B"); break;
    case "c": System.out.println("c | C"); break;
    case "d": System.out.println("d | D"); break;
    default:  System.out.println("You are doing it wrong");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are executing in java 7 and above

Try to convert letter to uppercase as follows

```
switch (charr.toUpperCase())
    {
    case "A" : System.out.println("a | A"); break;
    case "B" : System.out.println("b | B"); break;
    case "C" : System.out.println("c | C"); break;
    case "D" : System.out.println("d | D"); break;
    default:  System.out.println("You are doing it wrong");

    }
```

Hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Just use string as `charr = sc.next().toLowerCase()` or `charr = sc.next().toUpperCase()` and than use your case.Let's say you are using `toLowercase();` than

```
 switch (charr) {
case "a": System.out.println("a | A"); break;
case "b": System.out.println("a | A"); break;
case "c": System.out.println("a | A"); break;
case "d": System.out.println("a | A"); break;
default:  System.out.println("You are doing it wrong");
}
```

note: this will compile in JAVA 7 or else use char primitive type to compile the same